# Second instance of a money value print returns a value different than the first print with Python

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I'm working on a program that is a simulation of an order form/receipt. First, the program prints an invoice, then later prints a receipt based on which payment schedule the user selects (1-4 years)
My problem is that I can't find a way to get the invoice and receipt to print the same monthly payment. This is the code used for the invoice:

```
for NumYears in range (0, 4):
    NumYears += 1
    NumPayment = NumYears * 12
    FinanceFee = 39.99 * NumYears
    TotPrice = TotSalesPrice + FinanceFee
    MonPay = TotPrice / 12
```

it prints as:

```
# Years   # Payments   Financing Fee   Total Price   Monthly Payment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1         12             $39.99       $9,914.99            $826.25
    2         24             $79.98       $9,954.98            $829.58
    3         36            $119.97       $9,994.97            $832.91
    4         48            $159.96      $10,034.96            $836.25
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The second part of the code, for the receipt is:

```
MonPay1 = TotPrice / 12
MonPay2 = (TotPrice / 12) * 2
MonPay3 = (TotPrice / 12) * 3
MonPay4 = (TotPrice / 12) * 4

while True:
    if PayMethod == "1":
        print("Terms: 1       Total Payments: 12")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "2":
        print("Terms: 2       Total Payments: 24")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "3":
        print("Terms: 3       Total Payments: 36")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "4":
        print("Terms: 4       Total Payments: 48")
        break


while True:

    if PayMethod == "1":
        print(f"Monthly payment:       {MonPay1Dsp:>10s}")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "2":
        print(f"Monthly payment:       {MonPay2Dsp:>10s}")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "3":
        print(f"Monthly payment:       {MonPay3Dsp:>10s}")
        break
    elif PayMethod == "4":
        print(f"Monthly payment:       {MonPay4Dsp:>10s}")
        break
    else:
        break
```

it prints as:

```
    Sale price:             $5,000.00
    Trade Allowance:        $1,000.00
    Price after Trade:      $4,000.00
                            ----------
    HST:                      $750.00
    License Fee:               $75.00
    Transfer Fee:           $5,050.00
                            ----------
    Total Sales Cost:      $10,034.96
----------------------------------
Terms: 1       Total Payments: 12
Monthly payment:          $836.25
First payment date:   31-Jan-2022
```

What can I do to fix the discrepancy?

EDIT: Adding in all the calculations. I've gone over them a few times and can't find the error. Maybe I've just been looking at it too long... I don't know.

```
HST_FEE = .15
TRANS_FEE_LOW = 0.01
TRANS_FEE_HIGH = 0.026
LISC_FEE_LOW = 75.00
LISC_FEE_HIGH = 165.00

PriceAfterTrade = SellPrice - AmtTradeIn
Taxes = HST_FEE * SellPrice

if SellPrice <= 5000.00:
    LiscFee = LISC_FEE_LOW
else:
    LiscFee = LISC_FEE_HIGH
if SellPrice >= 20000.00:
    TransFee = (TRANS_FEE_HIGH * SellPrice) + SellPrice
else:
    TransFee = (TRANS_FEE_LOW * SellPrice) + SellPrice


TotSalesPrice = PriceAfterTrade + Taxes + LiscFee + TransFee
```

Comment: the bug is not in the code you pasted

Comment: The "Totals Sales Cost" in your receipt includes the TotSalesPrice of 9875 + a fee of 159.96, which is the financing fee for 4 years: look for the error in the part of the code (which you didn't include) that calculates the Total Sales Cost.

Comment: @JacobIRR I'll add all the calculations that are in the code... May be an error there.

Comment: @Swifty I've checked the code, and can't find any errors myself. I've posted all code relating to the calculations in an edit.

Comment: BTW, if you use `for NumYears in range(1, 5):` you don't need `NumYears += 1`

Comment: What is `MonPay1Dsp`?

Comment: What's the point of a `while` loop that breaks in all the `if` branches?

Comment: @Barmar The MonPay1Dsp/MonPay2Dsp are the receipt displays for the years, 1, 2, 3, etc. And I added the breaks because they were continuously looping otherwise, even with ending with else, break.

Comment: You don't need `while` at all if you don't need it to loop.

Comment: I think your calculation of the monthly payments is wrong. The monthly payment should be divided by the number of years, not multiplied. E.g. if you owe $240, that's $20/month for 1 year, or $10/month for 2 years.

Comment: And there's no need for all the `if` statements, it's simply `MonPay = TotPrice / 12 / int(PayMethod)`

Comment: Furthermore, your code doesn't include the calculation of the Total Sales Cost (where the financing fee intervenes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code just hit me: your calculations for MonPay1, ... all used TotPrice, with the value set at the end of the invoice loop, so the value for 4 years!

Here is the code I rewrote (based on my understanding of your different values).
You'll probably have to tweak some things to fit your needs.

```
# Data

SellPrice = 5000

AmtTradeIn = 1000

HST_FEE = .15
TRANS_FEE_LOW = 0.01
TRANS_FEE_HIGH = 0.026
LISC_FEE_LOW = 75.00
LISC_FEE_HIGH = 165.00

PriceAfterTrade = SellPrice - AmtTradeIn
Taxes = HST_FEE * SellPrice

if SellPrice <= 5000.00:
    LiscFee = LISC_FEE_LOW
else:
    LiscFee = LISC_FEE_HIGH
if SellPrice >= 20000.00:
    TransFee = (TRANS_FEE_HIGH * SellPrice) + SellPrice
else:
    TransFee = (TRANS_FEE_LOW * SellPrice) + SellPrice


TotSalesPrice = PriceAfterTrade + Taxes + LiscFee + TransFee

print(TotSalesPrice)


# Code for invoice

MonPay=[0]

for NumYears in range (1, 5):
    NumPayment = NumYears * 12
    FinanceFee = 39.99 * NumYears
    TotPrice = TotSalesPrice + FinanceFee
    MonPay.append(TotPrice / 12 / NumYears)
    print(MonPay[NumYears])
    

# Code for receipt

PayMethod = "1" #This is an example for testing purpose

print("Terms: " + PayMethod + "       Total Payments: "+str(12*int(PayMethod)))
print(f"Monthly payment:       ${MonPay[int(PayMethod)]}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head off the wall for hours now trying to figure this out. I'm in my first semester of software development so I'm not very adept yet, but it definitely didn't make sense why my code wasn't working. I appreciate your time and fresh eyes!